# update a column of numbers from value to (value * 1.3)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I want to update a columns("B") of numbers to +30%
I know I have solutions like a VBA "Loop" or an ADODB "UPDATE Query", But for some reason I can only use Excel Formula.
So, I wrote VBA code like

```
Columns("B").FormulaLocal = "=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()))*1.3"
```

And I got all "0" in Columns("B"). I know the formula may case "circular reference" problem, but is there a way to calculate "*1.3" only once?...Thx

Comment: plus, I do not want to use any "calculate-support-column"

Comment: The problem constraints seem artificial and make no sense: if you can only use a formula then that formula has to go *somewhere*, and you're saying you want to put it in the same cells as the values it operates on?

Comment: What I want to do is simply update a column of values to a new value base on its original value. because the amount of numbers is too big, loop row by row and updating is too slow, also "temp column" can even slower... the update query is too complicated in the real case...

Comment: simply select the range you want to change and write in the immediate window: `Selection.Value = Evaluate(Selection.Address & "*1.3")`... just keep in mind to only select the cells to change because empty cells will become `0`

Comment: cool! this is a better solution! thank you!

Comment: @johnn You are welcome :)

Comment: "for some reason I can only use Excel Formula" why? This is perverse, especially since you tried to use VBA to insert a formula (which makes things worse as it obscures why that approach can't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can use `PasteSpecial` to multiple the values.

[image]

```
Sub DirtyUpdate()

    Dim temp As Variant

    With Range("A1")
        temp = .Value
        .Value = 1.3
        .Copy
        Intersect(Columns("B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
                           Operation:=xlMultiply, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        .Value = temp
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rng, arr, r
Set rng = Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Columns(2))
arr = rng.Value
For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
  arr(r, 1) = 1.3 * arr(r, 1)
Next r
rng.Value = arr
```

Comment: Though this works, I feel you've missed the OPs original request to not use loops in VBA.

Comment: I don't feel obliged to stick to the OP's original request - avoiding loops was a performance constraint based on updating cell by cell directly on the worksheet.